# Фильтр для count в массиве php

Tags: php, массивы, count

Через $countDevicesRegSCCP = array_column($devicesSCCP, 'Xipv4Address'); получаю простой массив:

```
[0] => 172.19.18.18
[1] => 172.19.18.70
[2] => 172.19.18.69
[3] => 172.19.17.124
[4] => 172.19.18.71
[5] => 172.19.17.121
[6] => 0.0.0.0
[7] => 172.19.18.22
[8] => 0.0.0.0
[9] => 0.0.0.0
[10] => 0.0.0.0
[11] => 172.19.18.76
[12] => 172.19.18.80
[13] => 0.0.0.0
[14] => 172.17.65.45
```

далее мне надо посчитать значения которые !== '0.0.0.0', можно конечно через foreach, но я хочу через такую конструкцию, не получается ((

```
$countDevicesRegSCCP = count(array_filter(array_column($devicesSCCP, 'Xipv4Address')));
```

array_filter не считает 0.0.0.0 как пустое значение, поэтому не работает, можно это ранее преобразовать в NULL, можно написать callback функцию и это будет правильно, но я пока в этом не силен ((

Comment: array_filter  принимает массив и анонимную функцию, которая должна что-то возвращать.... посмотри в доки array_filter и попробуй хотя бы это реализовать.....

Comment: и такой вопрос: откуда этот массив прилетает? из БД?

Comment: колонка 'Xipv4Address' находится в массиве $devicesSCCP и прилетает она через API напрямую с Cisco CME

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавь колбек в `array_filter`:

```
$countDevicesRegSCCP = count(
    array_filter(
        array_column($devicesSCCP, 'Xipv4Address'),
        function($v) { return $v != '0.0.0.0'; }
   )
);
```

Хотя если подумать то это можно упростить:

```
$countDevicesRegSCCP = count(
    array_filter(
        $devicesSCCP,
        function($v) { return $v['Xipv4Address'] != '0.0.0.0'; }
   )
);
```

Начиная с версии 7.4 можно писать так:

```
$countDevicesRegSCCP = count(
    array_filter(
        $devicesSCCP,
        fn ($v) => $v['Xipv4Address'] != '0.0.0.0'
   )
);
```

Comment: А если ещё применить стрелочную функцию то ваще...))

Comment: Можно, да, но не факт что у ОП нужная версия.

Comment: php 8.1 как минимум

Comment: Покажите стрелочную фунцию )), тогда пара вечеров у меня зря не пройдет ))

Comment: `fn ($v) => $v['Xipv4Address'] != '0.0.0.0'`

Comment: можно наверное в принципе просто `fn $(v) => +$v['Xipv4Address'][0]`

Comment: @teran зачем же магию создавать на ровном месте?) никто, кроме специфичных кругов, это не оценит)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский я думал тут укоротить код хотели )